# AE Extendscript text layer cursor control

Tags: extendscript, after-effects

I'm trying to copy some text out of AE to the system clipboard with AE Extendscript.
After Effects doesn't provide for this in Extendscript directly.

I can put the text on a textlayer and then copy it to the clipboard with:

```
app.executeCommand(app.findMenuCommandId("Copy"));
```

But to do that the text has to be selected.
Which can be done with:

```
app.executeCommand(app.findMenuCommandId("Select All"));
```

However, the cursor must be in the field for that to work.

I'm trying to place the cursor in a textlayer text field with Extendscript in After Effects.
I can't see anyway to do that.

I've already managed to copy a variable's value to the system clipboard using the .bat method, but this won't work on all systems.  The best way is really to stay within AE.

Does anyone know how to get control of the text cursor in AE Extendscript?

Any ideas?

Comment: Its not the answer but do you need to use the cursor? You can get the text from a TextLayer via the sourceText property:   if((app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers[0] instanceof TextLayer)){
     alert(app.project.activeItem.selectedLayers[0].sourceText.value);
    }

Comment: Yea but there is no way of copying it to the clipboard in code.  The only way to do that without creating .bat files or apple script files is to somehow select the text and then use the app.execute...copy command above.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a vbs script and `sendkeys`?  You can create the script to do the sendkeys thing (since you can't do it in javascript), and then make your javascript file CALL the vbs script at the proper place.

Comment: I'm trying to make it work on different platforms, I guess since I already have it working on Win with a .bat file, maybe someone already has an applescript equivalent figured out.

Comment: You can't do sendkeys with javascript; I guess you already know that. Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what works in Extendscript:

```
//This works on Vista and Win 7,  XP requires the user to copy 'clip.exe' to the 'sys32' folder.
function copyTextToClipboard2(text)
{
   var folderForTempFiles = Folder.temp.fsName;
   //alert(folderForTempFiles)
   // create a new textfile and put the text into it
   var clipTxtFile =new File(folderForTempFiles + "/ClipBoard.txt"); 
   clipTxtFile.open('w'); 
   clipTxtFile.write(text); 
   clipTxtFile.close();

   // use the clip.exe to copy the contents of the textfile to the windows clipboard
   var clipBatFile =new File(folderForTempFiles + "/ClipBoard.bat"); 
   clipBatFile.open('w'); 
   clipBatFile.writeln("clip < " + folderForTempFiles + "/ClipBoard.txt"); 
   clipBatFile.close(); 
   clipBatFile.execute();
}
```

Does anyone have an apple equivalent worked out?

Comment: I posted the Mac version above accidentally.  It works well without resorting to using a console or terminal.  It uses: 'system.callSystem' with 'pbcopy'.  I can't seem to get a Windows version using 'clip.exe' to work though.  I moved the Windows problem to a new question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702235/is-windows-clip-blocked-in-adobe-extendscript)

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on a mac in After Effects CC, and it works well:

```
text = 'Lets copy some text'
var folderForTempFiles = Folder.temp.fsName;
// create a new textfile and put the text into it
var clipTxtFile =new File(folderForTempFiles + "/ClipBoard.txt"); 
clipTxtFile.open('w'); 
clipTxtFile.write(text); 
clipTxtFile.close();

system.callSystem("cat " + folderForTempFiles + "/ClipBoard.txt" + " | pbcopy");
```

Comment: I tried the same thing on Windows using 'clip' instead of 'pbcopy', but no matter what I tried I can't get 'system.callSystem' to work with 'clip'.  Is it blocked on Windows?