# Is Windows 'clip' blocked in Adobe ExtendScript?

Tags: windows, clipboard, clip, extendscript, after-effects

In Adobe ExtendScript (based on java script) you can trigger system commands as if you are in a Windows console with 'system.callSystem()'

This works:

```
system.callSystem("notepad c:/test.txt")
```

Notepad opens with the content of the file.

But these examples that try to paste to the clipboard don't work:"

```
system.callSystem('clip < c:/test.txt')
system.callSystem('dir | clip')
```

I've tried numerous variations with 'clip' and none of them work.

Is 'clip' blocked from working with ExtendScript, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think the problem is the stdio redirection operators (`|`, `<`, `>`) won't work when called that way. I suggest writing a `*.cmd` batch file containing the stdio redirection commands and then running that batch file from `callSystem`.

Comment: I have already done that, but I don't like the console flash when the batch file is run.  It may spook some users into thinking they have a virus.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe there is another way. e.g. creating a .bat file and executing it via `File('script.bat').execute()`

Comment: I'm doing that now with 'clipBatFile.execute()', but I'm trying to avoid this method.  It looks bad for software to have a console popping up like that.  On a Mac, I do: system.callSystem("cat " + folderForTempFiles + "/ClipBoard.txt" + " | pbcopy").  'pbcopy' is the Mac equivalent of 'clip' and it works fine.  I don't understand why the same thing won't work on Windows.

Comment: hm. Okay. I had a look around and the only thing I can think of is that it is a problem with admin rights. `dir | clip` looks like a valid command. Did you try to run AE as admin and execute that script again?